# react router - get current route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes, is it possible to get the current route name and apply its own handler?

```
var routes = (
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={OurSchoolsApp}>
    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={HomePage}  />
    <Route name="add-school" handler={AddSchoolPage}  />
    <Route name="calendar" handler={CalendarPage}  />
    <Route name="calendar-detail" path="calendar-detail/:id" handler={CalendarDetailPage} />
    <Route name="info-detail" path="info-detail/:id" handler={InfoDetailPage} />
    <Route name="info" handler={InfoPage} />
    <Route name="news" handler={NewsListPage} />
    <Route name="news-detail" path="news-detail/:id" handler={NewsDetailPage} />
    <Route name="contacts" handler={ContactPage} />
    <Route name="contact-detail" handler={ContactDetailPage} />
    <Route name="settings" handler={SettingsPage} />
</Route>
);
```

How do I get the current route name?

I want to do something like this?

```
Router.run(routes, function(Handler){
var mountNode = document.getElementById('app');

if(isRoute('home')){
        React.render(<Handler title="Home Page" /> , mountNode);
}else{
        React.render(<Handler title="default" /> , mountNode);
}

});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the callback function of Router.run is the state object. You can see here all the values that the state holds, you can use something from there.